# R squared for a regression plane without observations

Tags: regression, correlation, linear-regression

Assuming we have three random variables $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, and we want to estimate a least squares regression plane of the form $Z = a + bX + cY$. We do not know the individual observations, but we know all the means $\mu_X$,$\mu_Y$,$\mu_Z$, variances $\sigma_X^2$,$\sigma_Y^2$,$\sigma_Z^2$ covariances $\sigma_{XY}$,$\sigma_{XZ}$,$\sigma_{YZ}$ and correlations $\rho_{XY}$,$\rho_{XZ}$,$\rho_{YZ}$. Suppose we have estimated $a$, $b$, and $c$. How can we calculate the $R^2$ value given only this information?

Comment: Do you have formulas that relate $a$, $b$ and $c$ to those parameters? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Using the least squares approach, I found the following results: $b=(\sigma_{XZ}\sigma_{Y}-\sigma_{ZY}\sigma_{XY})/(\sigma_{X}\sigma_{Y}-\sigma_{XY}^2)$, c=$(\sigma_{ZY}\sigma_{X}-\sigma_{ZX}\sigma_{YX})/(\sigma_{Y}\sigma_{X}-\sigma_{YX}^2)$, $a=E[Z]-bE[X]-cE[Y]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition,
$$
R ^ 2 = 1 - \frac{Var(\epsilon | X, Y)}{Var(Z)} = 1 - \frac{Var(Z - a - bX - cY|X,Y)}{\sigma^2_Z}
$$
then,
$$
Var(Z - a - bX - cY|X,Y) = \sigma^2_Z + b^2\sigma^2_X - c^2\sigma^2_Y - 2b\sigma_{ZX} - 2c\sigma_{ZY} + 2bc\sigma_{XY}, 
$$
now, just plug-in your results and reduce the expression.